# JFileChooser inside a JFrame makes setVisible() freeze

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfilechooser

I have an assignment to show JFileChooser as part of a JFrame. So showing it as a dialog box is out.

I'm doing the most basic approach to adding it as a component to a yet invisible frame, and then the `setVisible()` call freezes instead of showing the frame.

What irks me the most is that one time out of ten the frame appears with the FileChooser just fine. This makes me think this is a concurrency issue.

Here's the minimal source code that still has the issue.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

class ApplicationFrame extends JFrame {
  JFileChooser fileChooser;

  public ApplicationFrame(String frameName) {
    super(frameName);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
    panel.add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    getContentPane().add(panel);
  }
}

public class lab7{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    ApplicationFrame windowForApplication = new ApplicationFrame("lab7");
    windowForApplication.setSize(600,600);
    windowForApplication.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

If you put a println after the final `setVisible`, it doesn't get called.

If you comment out `panel.add()`, the frame displays just fine.

What else should I do to display the file chooser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What irks me the most is that one time out of ten the frame appears with the FileChooser just fine.

All Swing component should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread. So the GUI creating code should be wrapped in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more information and an example of how this is done.

Your code (as is) actually works for me without problem. I'm using JDK7 on Windows 7, so it could be a version/platform issue. Again make sure the code executes on the EDT.

Also, class names ("lab7") should start with an upper case character. Doesn't matter if this is a SSCCE or not, be consistent.

Comment: Thanks, this was the exact issue. For reference, I'm using JDK8 on OSX 10.10. Also, it wouldn't reproduce under the IntelliJ debugger.